# Using File Streaming

Tags: java, filestream, bufferedreader

I want a program that saves what you enter into the Input Dialogs (after you click no on the first message dialog) for the next time you run the program. The next time I run the program and I click yes on the option dialog, I'm trying to get the text field to say what the user entered last time an input was made. The code at the bottom just sets the textfield blank for some reason..

```
public static String fn;
public static String sn;

public static int n;

File f = new File("test.txt");

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

    Object[] yesNo = {"Yes",
                      "No",};
    n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Would you like to use previously entered data?","Welcome Back?",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,  null, yesNo,yesNo[1]);

    if (n == 1){    
        for(fn=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first name?");!fn.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");fn.isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alphabet characters only.");
            fn=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first name?");
        }
        writeToFile();
        for(sn=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your second name?");!sn.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");sn.isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alphabet characters only.");
            sn=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your second name?");
        }

    if (n == 0){
        writeToFile();
        String fullName = writeToFile();

        text.setText("Welcome " + fullName + ".");
    }
    }
    //text.setText("Welcome " + fn + " " + sn + ".");
    b.setVisible(false);
    b.setEnabled(false);
    text.setVisible(true);
    text.setBounds(140,0,220,20);
    text.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    text.setEditable(false);
    text.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    pnlButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

}

private String writeToFile() {

    String nameToWrite = fn;
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    String savedName = "";
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        outStream.write(nameToWrite.getBytes());
        if (n==0){
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
            savedName = br.readLine();
        }
        if (n==1){
            text.setText("Welcome " + fn + ".");
        }
        //text.setText("Welcome " + savedName + " " + sn + ".");

        //System.out.println(savedName);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (null != outStream) {
            try {
                outStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
   return savedName;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open `outputStream` each time you call `writeToFile`, it automatically overwrites what was in the file to begin with. This means when you call `writeToFile` at the beginning of the `if` statement to handle the Yes option, you erase the previous contents.

To append, use the line `outStream = new FileOutputStream(f, true);`.

It may be better to consider moving ALL writing into the if block `n==1`.

An even better solution would be to have two methods; a `readFromFile` and a `writeToFile`. Also, consider using parameters that you pass to the methods instead of global variables.